# How to trigger ajax calls from a HTMLDocument Object in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, ajax

I am trying to retrieve some data from a web page by pulling the HTML into a string and parsing through it. The problem is that the information I want only shows up on the page when a user browses to the bottom of the page and triggers an Ajax call to update the DOM. Is there any way to do this in code without loading the HTML into a browser control and telling it to scroll?

Comment: please show up the code

Comment: Post the html that appears when the ajax call is triggered to a ASP.Net WebMethod. It would help if you would show some of your code. Since I don't know if I understand the question correctly

Comment: Who knows...  ...maybe there's a URL endpoint that you can query to get the same sort of results in JSON, without scraping...  ...maybe there's nothing you can do, without going out of your way to hack together a way to get the JavaScript to fire, and query the DOM over and over, for progress...  ...it comes down to the implementation and what you're trying to do with it -- neither of which we have insight into, currently.

Comment: Hey guys, sorry about not having any code snippets posted, I did find what I was looking for though. I am scraping table elements from a web page but the page only loads 15 or so elements per call and does not use URL based paging but instead uses ajax calls to fill in the data as a user scrolls down. This blog has the specific answers to my problem, I need to locate those ajax calls and probably just call them directly instead of trying to force the page to load the data, here's the link if anyone else is having similar problems: http://blog.hartleybrody.com/web-scraping/